# MongoDB integration with Informatica PowerCenter 9.1

Tags: oracle, mongodb, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I wish to use MongoDB as source and target, and perform ETL using Informatica PowerCenter 9.1.
I currently use Oracle 11g as the primary database and wish to migrate to MongoDB to see if MongoDB could be a better database. I also have MongoDB as the database for a few UI tools and wish to migrate the data to Oracle for reporting needs.
I have fair knowledge of Informatica. I would like to use MongoDB as a source and target.
Is this possible and if someone could guide me with some information.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible as long as you can create the sources in `Mapping Designer` => `Source Analyzer`, `Sources` top-bar menu. I'm not sure if you can access it by ODBC defined on your client machine, or if you need a dedicated connector that should be listed in the menu I've mentioned.

Once you import the source (and target respectively, in `Target Designer`), you should be able to create a copy of your mapping and replace the source and target with the new ones. Then you just need to create a workflow and set proper connections using server-defined ones.